# Confusion about assignment with commas

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment

What is the logic behind the following code?

```
var next, output = null, thisNode;
```

It appears like it's some type of coalescing like `var foo = bar || baz;`, but I'm not so familiar with the commas.

Comment: "Obtuse"? It's perfectly clearly laid out in the spec.

Comment: Yeah, but 3..toString() is clearly laid out in the spec too.

Comment: Not with two dots. And...your point? ;-)

Comment: No, two dots IS defined behavior. (int)(dot) needs to be followed by a digit, because it expects you're forming a float. This (3.toString()) throws an error. A (three)(dot), however, evaluates to (three)(dot)(zero), a float. THIS accepts a dot as a method-accessing character, which then lets you cast to string. Just saying that "Defined" and "useful/common/understandable" have only a bit of overlap, particularly WRT javascript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just a shorter way of writing:

```
var next;
var output = null;
var thisNode;
```

Comment: Just to emphasize for the OP: It's **exactly** the same as your rewritten version. Exactly, including the order (which can be important).

Comment: How is it that we have identical answers submitted at the same time, and there is this much difference between ratings?

Answer (score 3):

multiple variable declarations.

its the same as this:

```
var next;
var output = null;
var thisNode;
```